# JS Cannot load web worker module unless the worker.js is under public/

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, worker

I would like put my `worker.js` under the same `src/` directory as `main.js`, which loads the worker. (`src/` is parallel to `public/`) However I got the following error if `worker.js` is under `src/`.

`//in main.js
let worker = new Worker('./worker.js', {type:"module"});`

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

However if I put `worker.js` under `public/` (`index.html` is under `public/`), or any directory under `public/`, everything works fine. Seems like it can only load from `public/` aka. `http://<my domain>/worker.js` , if it is under any directory parallel to `public/`, then it cannot find it, aka. `http://<my domain>/../src/worker.js` doesn't work. Am I right on this?

Plus, in `worker.js`, I cannot import any thing in `node_modules/` like what I do for other js files in `src/`.

I assume these two questions are related. Could you please let me know the solutions?

(I am using worker-plugin, npm, react.)

thank you.

Comment: I think you are mixing up the client and server side. Are you trying to reference certain node modules from client side? That doesn't sound right. You need to create a bundle for that to work. Google `webpack`.

Comment: You are right. I need to bundle everything. At least worker-plugin document says so. I am pretty new to webpack. Could you please explain a little bit more the right way of doing it?

Comment: Follow the steps explained here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your entry file, webpack tries to create a dependency tree. So it looks trough all the files that are being imported through a import/require statement, and then it tries to bundle your files into a single bundle. However, it does not happen with the worker constructor. Thus, webpack does not see your worker file as a dependency of your single bundle, and, therefore, it does not bundle it. So, to make this work, you can use a loader in you webpack configuration such as worker-loader (https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/worker-loader/), adding a rule in your webpack config file.